# How to Display This Django Form Error?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

How do you display an error in a Django form when you are cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other?  I have a Django form in which I display field errors like this [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhVKG.jpg).  It requires that I display the form's errors attribute:

```
# signup.html
<form action="{% url 'create-account' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {% if create_account_form.errors %}           # <- attribute
            <p class="errornote">
            {% if form.errors.items|length == 1 %}
                Please correct the error below.
            {% else %}
               Please correct the errors below.
            {% endif %}
            </p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ create_account_form.username.errors }}     # <- attribute
        {{ create_account_form.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ create_account_form.password1.errors }}
        {{ create_account_form.password1 }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ create_account_form.password2.errors }}
        {{ create_account_form.password2 }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ create_account_form.user_type_cd.errors }}
        <label for="id_user_type_cd" id="user_type_cd">This account is for a</label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        {{ create_account_form.user_type_cd }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        By clicking "Sign up" you agree to the <a href="{% url 'terms-of-service' %}">Terms of Service</a>.
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

I customize the form error messages using the error_messages argument:

```
# account/forms.py
class CreateAccountForm(forms.Form):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (...)
    username = forms.CharField(
        error_messages = {'required': "Username is required."}
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        error_messages = {'required': "Password is required."}
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        error_messages = {'required': "Passwords must match."}
    )
    user_type_cd = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = USER_TYPE_CHOICES,
        error_messages={'required': 'Account type is required'}
    )
```

The problem is that when I try to display an error message from a custom clean method, the error message doesn't render properly because it isn't in the error_messages argument.  See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLoBl.jpg).

```
# account/forms.py
def clean(self):
    """ Check that passwords match. """
    super(forms.Form, self).clean()
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            self._errors['password1'] = "Passwords must match."
    return self.cleaned_data
```

How to I get the error identified in my clean method into the password1 field's error_messages argument so that my template formats and renders it properly like it does with the other form fields?  I tried doing the following in the clean method but neither approach worked and I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
# This doesn't work. It assumes that I've defined password1's error_messages like this:
password1 = forms.CharField(
  error_messages = {'required': "Password is required", 'mismatch': "Passwords must match."}
)
...
from django.forms import util
raise util.ValidationError(self.password1.error_messages['mismatch'])

# This doesn't work either.
raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done it already, in your first snippet. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the rest of that code.

As an alternative to your already working code though, can you can use the [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method. See also the full discussion under [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Thanks so much, Daniel.  The first snippet worked properly and the second snippet displays the error, but it's just not in error_messages and so it doesn't get the error-formatting.  I used add_error per your answer and it works perfectly!